# Can't install Syncdrive - dependency is not satisfiable gambas3-runtime ( =3.5)

Tags: software-installation

That's schreenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When installing syncdrive.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: What was the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: I don't know what you are telling me.

Comment: post the output of the command `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Gambas v3.5 is not available in the official Ubuntu software sources.

According to the [Gambas web page](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html) it is available from the [PPA ppa:nemh/gambas3](https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/gambas3)

See [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) if you don't know what a PPA is.

Comment: I downloaded gambas3-3.5.2 but I don't know how to install it?

Comment: Just add the PPA to your software sources and try again to install `syncdrive`. The package manager than automatically installs Gambas3 for you.

Comment: I downloaded gambas3-3.5.2.tar.bz2 but I couldn't install. it opens  as archive.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) if you really want to install from that. But it's much more difficult than using the package manager.